# issue with returning Struct from C to Python using ctypes

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

I am trying to get the values of C struct member variables from within python using ctypes. My expected return values for x and y are 10 and 20 respectively. I am thinking I might be neglecting something subtle but not sure what it is. The output I get is 0 for x and y as shown at the end of the post. Any pointers appreciated.

**Python code:**

```
import ctypes
import os

class Point(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", ctypes.c_int), 
                ("y", ctypes.c_int)]

directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(directory)
source = directory + "\\cstruct.so"
 
clibrary = ctypes.CDLL(source)

clibrary.getPoint.restype = ctypes.POINTER(Point)
p1 = clibrary.getPoint()
print(p1.contents.x, p1.contents.y)
```

**C code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};


struct Point* getPoint()
{
    struct Point *p;
    p->x = 10;
    p->y = 20;
    return p;
}
```

C code is compiled into a shared library file cstruct.so which is called in the python file.

**Python Output:**

```
0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue is. I had to dynamically allocate the size of the `struct Point` in the C file. Previously, I had not done this. This solves the issue.

Just modified the first line in the `struct Point* getPoint()` function as shown below.

```
struct Point *p = malloc(sizeof(struct Point));
```

Also added a C function in the c file to free the memory from the struct pointer as shown below.

```
void free_mem(struct Point* p) 
{
    free(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The original code didn't allocate memory for the structure, so I expect the "issue" was a crash.

One solution is to change the code and let Python allocate and manage the memory to eliminate the possibility of a memory leak when a heap-allocated object is returned but not freed.

test.c

```c
#define API __declspec(dllexport)  // For Windows

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

API void getPoint(struct Point* p) {
    p->x = 10;
    p->y = 20;
}
```

test.py

```py
import ctypes as ct
import os

class Point(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", ct.c_int), 
                ("y", ct.c_int)]
    # define display representation of a Point so it can print itself.
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Point(x={self.x}, y={self.y})'

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.getPoint.argtypes = ct.POINTER(Point),
dll.getPoint.restype = None

p = Point()                # Python creates an instance and manages the lifetime.
dll.getPoint(ct.byref(p))  # Pass by reference to C
print(p)                   # Uses __repr__() to print itself
```

Output:

```
Point(x=10, y=20)
```